# visual studio Immediate Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on debuging some logic and wanted to see if there is a way I can display this full list?

```
Cache.Select(Cache => Cache.Id.ToString());
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<OrderTemplateTool.Data.Dictionary, string>}
    [0]: "4c5d3244-40cf-4ee2-a874-3f269b441a6d"
    [1]: "2873049b-968a-4c9e-977f-38a8f14a35b6"
    [2]: "272e63d0-494e-4d61-b621-c70a137b4b93"
....
    [98]: "3f021aae-d54f-4d23-a257-c507b14ee46c"
    [99]: "8b54508f-d6b4-4ced-ab58-5d3d3815d7bd"
    < More... (The first 100 of 209 items were displayed.) >
```

Comment: Print each item individually?

Comment: That or print 100 to 209

Comment: Have you tried `.Skip(100)`?

Comment: something like this `Cache.Skip(100).Select(Cache => Cache.Id.ToString());` I still get record [0] -[99]

Comment: @Jefferson That's weird. Are these 100 items the same as without the `Skip` call?

Comment: Yes they are the same with and without the `Skip` tried this too `Cache.Select(Cache => Cache.Id.ToString()).Skip(100);`

Comment: You can output to local file with File.AppendAllLines(c:\\temp:\\myapp1.txt,JsonStringData); I have used this approach when debugger is failing to show me all the data in any scenario.